# Cannot View WSO2 ESB Proxy / API in WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

I've created a simple pass through proxy and enabled statistics in ESB. I fired up the DAS server locally as well. Didn't change any default settings in local ESB or DAS except for some properties in synapse.properties file. I made a couple of requests to ESB but once logged to DAS I couldn't see the proxy I created nor any data.[image]

Any idea on what is wrong here? thanks

Answer (score 0):

ESB analytics have of artifacts in order to receive ESB events, process them and visualize them in the dashboard. These artifacts are not shipped with WSO2DAS pack. There is a carbon archive (CAR) file called ESB analytics which consist of these artifacts. You can place them in following path of WSO2DAS pack directory. Then start the server you will find a pre created dashboard.

```
<WSO2_DAS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps
```

You can refer WSO2 ESB Analytics Documentation [2] for details.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/51486503/ESB_Artifacts_1.0.0.car?version=1&modificationDate=1465535756000&api=v2

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Monitoring+WSO2+ESB+with+WSO2+ESB+Analytics